# Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, attributes, attributeerror

`self.dataset` was initialized as `None` but updated in the `read_archive` function to read into the csv files. However, my code still raise `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'` error.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import os
from collections import OrderedDict
import shutil
import re


class DataProcesser:

    def __init__(self, raw_path, col_id='ID', col_class='class', col_classname='class_name', col_set='set',
                 read_on_init=True, **kwargs):

        self.archive = ZipFile('data.zip', 'w')
        self.raw_path = raw_path
        self.col_id = col_id
        self.col_class = col_class
        self.col_classname = col_classname
        self.col_set = col_set
        self.dataset = None
        self.dataset_cropped = None
        self.id_set = None
        self.classes = None
        self.train_set = None
        self.validation_set = None
        self.test_set = None
        self.logs = []
        self.stats = None
        self.flag_subset = False
        self.flag_process = False
        self.flag_split = False
        self.measurement_df = None

    def raw_file_processing(self):

        # If the path contains HTAN CODEX data, perform the following processing steps
        if os.path.isdir(self.raw_path):

            self.col_classname = self.raw_path.iloc[2]

            # Dummy-code the classes
            self.col_class = pd.get_dummies(self.col_classname)

            # Create the ID series by concatenating columns 1-3
            self.col_id = self.raw_path.assign(
                ID=self.raw_path[['cell_id:cell_id', 'region:region', 'tile_num:tile_num']].apply(
                    lambda row: '_'.join([str(each) for each in row]), axis=1))
            self.col_id = self.raw_path.drop(columns=['cell_id:cell_id', 'region:region', 'tile_num:tile_num'])

            # Obtain measurement info
            # Normalize data against blank/empty columns
            # log-transform the data
            for col in self.raw_path[9:]:
                if re.findall(r"Blank|Empty", col):
                    background = col
                else:
                    for index, row in col:
                        norm_data = row / background
                        self.measurement_df = np.log2(norm_data)

        return self.raw_path, self.col_id, self.col_class, self.measurement_df

    def dataset_csv(self):

        # If the path contains HTAN CODEX data, perform the following processing steps
        if os.path.isdir(self.raw_path):
            """Col 1: ID
            Col 2: class
            Col 3-n: measurements"""
            id_col = self.col_id

            self.col_class = self.col_class.to_frame()

            frames = [id_col, self.col_class, self.measurement_df]
            self.dataset = pd.concat(frames)
            dat_df = self.dataset.to_csv("../input_data/data/dataset.csv")
        return self.dataset, dat_df

    def zip_files(self):

        # Create a ZipFile object for dataset.csv, classes.csv, and id_set.csv
        self.archive = shutil.make_archive(self.archive_path, "zip", "../input_data/data/")
        return self.archive

    def read_archive(self, datatable=True, **kwargs):
        if datatable:
            try:
                from datatable import fread
                self.dataset = fread(self.archive.open('dataset.csv'), **kwargs).to_pandas()
                self.id_set = fread(self.archive.open('id_set.csv'), **kwargs).to_pandas()
                self.classes = fread(self.archive.open('classes.csv'), **kwargs).to_pandas()
            except ModuleNotFoundError:
                warnings.warn('datatable module not found, using pandas instead. To prevent this message from appearing'
                              ' use "datatable = False" when reading the archive.')
                self.dataset = pd.read_csv(self.archive.open('dataset.csv'))
                self.id_set = pd.read_csv(self.archive.open('id_set.csv'))
                self.classes = pd.read_csv(self.archive.open('classes.csv'))
        else:
            self.dataset = pd.read_csv(self.archive.open('dataset.csv'))
            self.id_set = pd.read_csv(self.archive.open('id_set.csv'))
            self.classes = pd.read_csv(self.archive.open('classes.csv'))
        self.check_datasets()
        return None

    def detect_groups_times(self, return_groups=True, return_times=True, return_times_pergroup=True):

        if return_times_pergroup and not return_times:
            return_times = True
            warnings.warn(
                '"return_times" is False but "return_times_pergroup" is True. "return_times" will be set to True.')
        out = {}
        colnames = list(self.dataset.columns.values)
        colnames.remove(self.col_id)
        colnames.remove(self.col_class)
        groups = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([i.split('_')[0] for i in colnames]))
        if return_groups:
            out['groups'] = groups
        if return_times:
            times = [int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in colnames]
            out['times'] = [min(times), max(times)]
            if return_times_pergroup:
                out['times_pergroup'] = {}
                for group in groups:
                    group_columns = [i for i in colnames if search('^{0}_'.format(group), i)]
                    group_times = [int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in group_columns]
                    out['times_pergroup'][group] = [min(group_times), max(group_times)]
        return out


input_path = "//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/melissachua/CODEX/input_data"
# Open all the subfolders within path
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), "r") as data:
            raw_files = pd.read_csv(data)

meas_var = None
start_time = None
end_time = None

# The data object is used to automatically derive some parameters (e.g. number of classes)
data = DataProcesser(raw_files, datatable=False)

# Update default for the data
data.read_archive()
meas_var = data.detect_groups_times()['groups'] if meas_var is None else meas_var
```

Traceback

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> /tmp/ipykernel_17688/1589195238.py in <module>
>       3 
>       4 # Update default for the data
> ----> 5 meas_var = data.detect_groups_times()['groups'] if meas_var is None else meas_var
>       6 start_time = data.detect_groups_times()['times'][0] if start_time is None else start_time
>       7 end_time = data.detect_groups_times()['times'][1] if end_time is None else end_time
>
> ~/CODEX/Notebooks/../source/load_data.py in detect_groups_times(self, return_groups, return_times,
> ```
>
> return_times_pergroup)
> 250             warnings.warn('"return_times" is False but "return_times_pergroup" is True. "return_times" will be set to True.')
> 251         out = {}
> --> 252         colnames = list(self.dataset.columns.values)
> 253         colnames.remove(self.col_id)
> 254         colnames.remove(self.col_class)
>
> ```
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'
> ```

Comment: You initialize `self.dataset` to `None` in your constructor: `self.dataset = None`. Between that and your method call `data.detect_groups_times()`, nothing sets `self.dataset` to anything else before you try converting to a `list` `colnames = list(self.dataset.columns.values)`. You say it's updated in the `read_archive` function but no such function call occurs in your code.

Comment: I was trying to amend the original code (https://github.com/pertzlab/CODEX/blob/master/source/load_data.py). When I run the original code, I didn't get error. I modified the other parts of the code but did not change anything related to `self.dataset`. Why did my code stop working? How can I make it work?

Comment: I've added `self.dataset = pd.concat(frames)` in the `dataset_csv` function. But it is still raising the same error.

Comment: Just call `data.read_archive()` before `meas_var = data.detect_groups_times()['groups'] if meas_var is None else meas_var`